# Error has occurred:: 'EmployeeDataAccess.EmployeeDBEntities': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

```
public class EmployeesController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Get()
    {
        using (EmployeeDBEntities entities = new EmployeeDBEntities())
        {
            return entities.Employees.ToList();
        }
    }
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Get(int id)
    {
        using (EmployeeDBEntities entities = new EmployeeDBEntities())
        {
            return entities.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Implement Idisposable interface in your EmployeeDBEntities class and implement it's dispose method.

Comment: Another solution is not to use using statement

Comment: Hi Utkarsh. Can I offer you a few tips when asking questions. Keep titles short, the title you have used should probably be part of the body. Also, remember you are asking a question. Rather than posting code into the body you could say "Can someone help me understand why this code isn't working?" Then paste your code, and state the error you are getting. To answer your question, you cannot put a class into a using statement unless it implements IDisposable. My suggestion is to disregard the using statement and just create a variable of type EmployeeDBEntities

Comment: @ConorGallagher thank you for yoour concern. I'll keep in mind your suggestion for future.

Answer (score 0):

Your class EmployeeDBEntities have to implements IDisposible to use `using`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Or, do not use `using`

```
EmployeeDBEntities entities = new EmployeeDBEntities();
return entities.Employees.ToList();
```